# Error - Artifactory response: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm trying to download a file from my Jfrog artifactory to my local machine with CLI command:

`jfrog rt dl --user *username* --password *password* -url  https://*domain*.jfrog.io/artifactory/*my-folder-name*/ --flat=false * c:/jfrog/`

I'm getting:

```
Log path: C:\Users\Administrator\.jfrog\logs\jfrog-cli.2020-08-19.18-38-11.3780.log 
{   "status": "failure",   
    "totals": {
        "success": 0,
        "failure": 0   
    } 
} 
[Error] Download finished with errors, please review the logs.
```

From the logs:

`[Error] Artifactory response: 405 Method Not Allowed`

but, when I'm running `jfrog rt ping` I'm getting

```
"OK"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting 405 is that JFrog CLI is trying ping the Artifactory using the --url https://*domain*.jfrog.io/artifactory/*my-folder-name*/. To overcome this you should try to download using the below JFrog CLI,

> jfrog rt dl --user *username* --password *password* -url
> https://*domain*.jfrog.io/artifactory/ "<repository_key>/"  --flat=false *
> c:/jfrog/

For example, if I want to download any artifacts from the "generic-local" repository under "jars" folder then my JFrog CLI command would be as below,

> $ jfrog rt dl --user admin --password password -url
> http://localhost:8081/artifactory "generic-local/jars/"
> --flat=false

It should download all the artifacts under "generic-local/jars" under the current directory.